# How to secure ClickOnce Deployment with Visual Studio using IIS7.5

Tags: deployment, ftp, iis-7.5

In IIS7 I have a FTP site and Website for deployment. Everything works fine, the only thing I do not like is that theoretically every user can tamper with the application files on FTP because read/write access is configured for anonymous.

I fixed this by enabling and configuring "Basic Authentication" instead of "Anonymous Authentication" and now I have to provide my domain password during deployment.

Great! So what's the problem?

[image: FTP Login Screen]

The problem is that the password is transferred unencrypted.

**Question(s):** How can I make sure that the password is encrypted (can I use sftp instead of ftp?)

Any thoughts about certificates? I already tried with a self signed certificate but didn't managed to get things running.

Are there other way to deploy software more secure? I tried over https but I don't have the `Frontpage Extension` which is necessary for this.

Comment: what it has to do with clickonce? clearly your problem is how to setup secure ftp connection with IIS - and there is lot of good links if you google: http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/using-ftp-over-ssl-in-iis-7

Comment: You're right. I was looking for some best practice. Maybe there are other ways to achieve what I want? thought I did not express this clearly enough.